# docker compose (FastAPI, Python)

Tags: python, docker-compose, fastapi, minio

I am a beginning ptogrammer. I have created a docker-compose file with services, one of them is Minio for transfering photos. On the local host the path works while on the server it doesn't.Would you please advise, how to solve the issue? Thanks a lot in advance

```py
version: '3.3'

services:
  fastapi_server:
    container_name: fastapi_server
    image: jrtec/agregator:main
    restart: always
    command: "sh -c 'alembic upgrade head && python app/initial_data.py && gunicorn -w 3 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app  --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --preload --log-level=debug --timeout 120'"
    volumes:
      - ./agregator:/code
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file: ".env"
    depends_on:
      - database
    links:
      - traefik-proxy:storage.localhost
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi_local.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi_local.rule=Host(`fastapi.${LOCAL_1}`, `fastapi.${LOCAL_2}`, `fastapi.${EXT_ENDPOINT1}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi_local_base.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi_local_base.rule=Host(`${LOCAL_1}`, `${LOCAL_2}`, `${EXT_ENDPOINT1}`)"
      - traefik.http.services.fastapi_localservice.loadbalancer.server.port=8000
  
  database:
    image: bitnami/postgresql:13.3.0
    restart: always
    container_name: database
    env_file: ".env"
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./db_docker:/bitnami/postgresql
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USERNAME=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD= "trust"
      - POSTGRESQL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD= ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      
  redis_server:
    container_name: redis_server
    image: "redis:alpine"
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 6379
    env_file: .env

  nginx_server:
    container_name: nginx_server
    restart: unless-stopped
    logging:
      driver: none
    image: "nginx:latest"
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - ./static:/code/static
      - ./nginx-config-files/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx-config-files/app.nginx.template:/etc/nginx/templates/app.nginx.template
      - "${EB_LOG_BASE_DIR:-./nginx-config-files}/nginx-proxy:/var/log/nginx"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx_local.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx_local.rule=Host(`nginx.${LOCAL_1}`, `nginx.${LOCAL_2}`, `nginx.${EXT_ENDPOINT1}`)"
      - traefik.http.services.nginx_local_service.loadbalancer.server.port=8080

  minio_server:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: minio_server
    volumes:
      - ./minio/data:/data
    expose:
      - 9000
      - 9091
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: http://stash.localhost
    command: "server /data --console-address ':9090'"    
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.minio.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.minio.service=minio
      - traefik.http.routers.minio.rule=Host(`storage.${LOCAL_1}`, `storage.${LOCAL_2}`, `storage.${EXT_ENDPOINT1}`)      
      - traefik.http.services.minio.loadbalancer.server.port=9000
      - traefik.http.routers.minio-console.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.minio-console.service=minio-console
      - traefik.http.routers.minio-console.rule=Host(`stash.${LOCAL_1}`, `stash.${LOCAL_2}`, `stash.${EXT_ENDPOINT1}`)     
       - traefik.http.services.minio-console.loadbalancer.server.port=9090

  traefik-proxy:
    container_name: traefik-proxy
    restart: always
    image: "traefik:latest"
    command:
      - "--providers.docker=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - ./traefik/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./traefik/.htpasswd:/.htpasswd
      - "${EB_LOG_BASE_DIR:-./traefik}/traefik-proxy:/logs"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.${LOCAL_1}`, `traefik.${LOCAL_2}`, `traefik.${EXT_ENDPOINT1}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.usersfile=/.htpasswd"
```

I checked the listening ports and I was looking for a way to run Traefik and Nginx side by side

Comment: Needs a bit more info. What path are you talking about, and what do you mean by 'works' or 'doesn't work'? Help us understand more about the situation. What kind of error messages are you getting?